# Why kmeans cluster breakup is like this

Tags: k-means, supervised-learning, clustering, spectral-clustering

I have a galaxy spectrum data set (total 22000). Similar to an electronic wave data, two dimensional (Flux vs Wavelength). A typical set of wavelength plot looks like below
[image]

Now I am doing kmeans on this data set to cluster them based on their spectrum shape/pattern only (using sci-kit learn). Some results of the k means clustering is baffling me, I have made a flow chart of how the candidates clustered as I would go on increasing the number of clusters from `k=2` to `k=5`. The flow chart graph of the division of candidates is below (this is on a smaller subset),
[image]

Now my most basic question is why is the division of points in clusters happening like it is seen in the plot, as we traverse down the graph. More specifically, why for example in `k=4` case in `Cluster=1` it makes a group with such a mix bag ? couldnt kmeans instead select it's constituent `1078` or `580` candidates into a single (more cleaner) cluster ?
Also is it a coincidence that there is always an identified `13` members group (in golden arrow) (or a `47`).

Comment: It is an interesting way to visualize k-means. Since you have a 2D data, have you tried visualizing it something like the graph you see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-cluster-plot-kmeans-digits-py)?

Comment: @sai , individual waves are of array 5000 length. So it is not a 2D data. Kmeans would cluster based on the wavelength distribution on this arrays. so it is a high dimenionsal data. Am I correct ?

Comment: I do not think the length matters. Just the space in which your waves vary i.e., the min and max values of the flux and wavelength matter.

Comment: How do you generate that chart? What do the individual arrows/colors mean?

Comment: You can't visualize directly in 2D as you are in 5000D however you can use a tool such as t-SNE to visualize your data points in 2D (try different parameters of perplexity) and check in the 2D space from t-SNE how are distributed clusters from KNN (@ sai I think KNN is not performed on indivual (time, value) points but rather on the whole signals, signals with similar shapes will be closer)

Comment: @BenReiniger I generate the chart by hand. I use the ID of the candidates to check their distribution. The colours were initially red and blue, to identify the two clusters, the additional golden arrow was done just to point out that this number of candidate is identified throughout, which I find strange

Comment: @sai I could make those type of plots, as you suggested. But I am nor sure how to interpret them.Is there a place here where I can post them ?

Comment: @AyanMitra you can edit your post and include new information